# In general Western languages, how to terminate a phrase, which starts with a question but ends with a statement?

Tags: grammar, questions, punctuation

I just entered the following comment on a StackOverflow question:

> Is this a purely theoretical question, because `sleep 5` without any quotes is working fine?

I have no idea if this sentence is correctly ended, because:

- It starts with a question "Is this a purely theoretical question"
- It ends with a statement "because `sleep 5` without any quotes is working fine"

This gives two possibilities:

- As the main phrase is a question, the entire sentence should end with a question mark (?)
- As the last phrase is a statement, the entire sentence should end with a simple point (.)

So, which one is correct:

- Is this a purely theoretical question, because sleep 5 without any quotes is working fine?

Or:

- Is this a purely theoretical question, because sleep 5 without any quotes is working fine.

Is there a general rule for this in European languages? (I'm interested in Dutch, German, French, Spanish and English)

Comment: I had the exact same question in a different context. My answer to myself is that the main clause is the leader, and everything else follows. Therefore, the punctuation must respect the main clause. But I do not have a scientific reference for this answer - ergo, the comment.

Comment: I've removed the Indo-European tag as punctuation systems (being part of writing systems more generally) need not group the same way as the languages they're used for, so there's no reason to expect more uniformity within Indo-European languages than e.g. between Spanish & Basque

Comment: Despite being disguised as a cross-language question, it is in fact just a bunch of questions (one for each language) about correct punctuation in each of them. Use the language specific stackexchanges like [elu.se], [french.se], and [german.se] when available, or seek another venue when no language specific stackexchange exists.

Comment: @SirCornflakes: that distinction between those languages is in fact one point of my question: "Is there one general rule for all mentioned languages or is there a separate rule for every individual language?".

Comment: It is quite possible that nobody has made up a rule to cover this case, or that different people have made up different rules.

Comment: @ColinFine: hence my question :-)

Comment: Note that punctuation is not part of (the universal human experience of) language, it is part of (the set of various invented technologies called) writing.

Comment: I would lose the comma after because.

Comment: Different publishers have different rules about this. The problem is that the question mark appears on both Y/N and WH- questions, but it only represents a question intonation on Y/N questions, since WH- questions have no characteristic intonation. So the rule of "write it if you hear it" can't work. Rhetorical WH-  sentences don't need a question mark, in general, provided the question marking happens at the beginning and is separated from the end of the sentence.

Comment: Make it two different sentences.